# Unzip password protected file in SSIS using Ionic.Zip dll

Tags: c#, dll, ssis, zip, unzip

I got requirement to unzip a file which contains password protected text files in zip file.which have to be done in SSIS package..

I have googled and download a dll called Ionic.Zip to used in script task.

i have used the below code using c# in script task..

```
  using Ionic.Zip;
  
 

  public void Main()        
  {             
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    start obj= new start();
    obj.decrypt();
  }
  public class start
   {
     public void decrypt()
       {
        string sfilepath ="E:\\shekar\\CIF_Files\\USAGE.zip";                       
                
        ZipFile fileToExtract = new ZipFile(sfilepath);
        fileToExtract.Password = "ftp122";
        fileToExtract.ExtractAll("E:\\shekar\\CIF_Files");
        }
    }
```

But i am getting an exception msg as below

[image]

I Had google a lot. but can't find correct solution. does any one prove me answer

Comment: Have you tried writing a Console C# application which can handle the script side of the problem first?  To make sure that logic is correct?  

How did you add a reference to the DLL?

Comment: Yes i tried in console application also..i got the same error.i have added the dll in refernce folder.

Comment: You need to add the DLL as a reference.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx Try that and see where you get.  placing a dll in a folder is not going to magically hook into the applcation.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the below. It will give you an idea of how it's being used in C# environment. Remember to check all the different Solutions:

[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/411954/How-to-zip-and-unzip-file-using-Csharp-net-and-Asp)